# How to improve performance on a single table query in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to figure out why a query against a single table is taking far longer than I think it should. I am sure this question has a simple answer, but I've been scratching my head now for a while and may just not be seeing the forest for the trees.

I have a table, roughly 35 columns wide, with a standard assortment of columns (few int's, bunch of varchar()'s of sizes ranging from 10 to 255, pretty basic), on which I have placed a Clustered Index on the column let's call "PackageID" for the sake of explanation. There are a little north of a Million records in this table so there's a fair amount of data to comb through, and there may one or more records with the same PackageID due to the nature of the records, but it's just a single 'flat' table.

Hitting the table I have a Stored Procedure that takes in a `varchar(max)` argument that could be a single PackageID or it could be a comma delimited list of 10, 50, 500, or more. The SProc calls a fairly standard simple `Split()` function (found here and on other sites) that splits the list returning the values as a table, which I then attempt to filter against my table for results. The ID's are int values currently up to 5 digits in length, in the future it will grow but only 5 right now.

I have tried a couple variations on the query inside the SProc (just the query here for brevity):

```sql
SELECT PackageID, Column01, Column02, Column03, ... , ColumnN
FROM MyTable
WHERE PackageID IN (SELECT SplitValue FROM dbo.Split(@ListOfIDs, ','))
```

and

```sql
;WITH cteIDs AS (
    SELECT SplitValue 
    FROM dbo.Split(@ListOfIDs, ',')
)
SELECT PackageID, Column01, Column02, Column03, ... , ColumnN
FROM MyTable m
INNER JOIN cteIDs c ON m.PackageID = c.SplitValue
```

Running from SSMS, on both the Estimated Execution Plan shows as being identical, and take roughly the same amount of time. When the `@ListOfIDs` is short, the records return quickly, but as the IDs list grows (and it can get to hundreds or more) the execution time can go to minutes or longer. There are no triggers, nothing else is using it, the query isn't being blocked or deadlocked by anything I can tell... it just runs slow.

I feel like I am missing something crazy simple here, but I am just not seeing it.

Appreciate any help, thanks!

**UPDATE**

This is the `Split()` function I am using, it's something I pulled from here I don't know how long ago, and have been using ever since. If there is a better one I am happy to switch, this one just worked so I never gave it another thought...

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] 
( 
        @String VARCHAR(max), 
        @Delimiter VARCHAR(5) 
) 
RETURNS @SplittedValues TABLE 
( 
  OccurenceId SMALLINT IDENTITY(1,1), 
  SplitValue VARCHAR(max) 
) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @SplitLength INT 

    WHILE LEN(@String) > 0 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @SplitLength = (CASE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String) 
                                    WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@String) 
                                    ELSE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String) -1 
                                END)

        INSERT INTO @SplittedValues 
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, 1, @SplitLength)

        SELECT @String = (CASE (LEN(@String) - @SplitLength) 
                                WHEN 0 THEN '' 
                                ELSE RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - @SplitLength - 1) 
                          END) 
    END 
    RETURN 
END 

GO
```

**UPDATE - Testing Comment Suggestions**

I have attempted to try out the suggestions in the comments, and here is what I have found out...

- Table size: 1,081,154 records
- Unique "PackageID" count: 16008 ID
- List test size: 500 random IDs (comma delimited string arg input)

When I run (in SSMS) the query using just the `Split()` function it takes on average 309 seconds to return 373,761 records.

When I run the query but first dump the `Split()` results into a @TempTable (with Primary Key Index) and join that against the table, it takes on average 111 seconds to return the same 373,761 records.

I understand this is a lot of records, but this is a flat table with a Clustered Index on the PackageID. The query is a very basic select just asking for the records matching on the ID. There is no calculations, no processing, no other JOINS to other tables, CASE statements, groupings, havings, etc. I am failing to understand why it is taking so long to execute the query. I've seen other queries with massive logic involved return thousands of records sub-second, why does this "simple" looking thing get bogged down?

**UPDATE - Adding Exec Plan**

As requested, here is the Execution Plan for the query I am running. After dumping split values of the incoming delimited list of ID's into a @TempTable, the query is simply asking for all records out of Table A ("MyTable") with matching ID's found in Table B (the @TempTable). That's it.

[image: Execution Plan for Query]

**Update - Order By**

In the attached Execution Plan, noted in the comments, there was an ORDER BY that appeared to be consuming a fair amount of overhead. I removed this from my query and re-ran my tests, which resulted in a minimal improvement in execution time. On a test run that previously took 7 minutes, without the ORDER BY would complete in 6:30 to 6:45 minutes.

At this stage of the game, I am about to chalk this up to a case of Data Volume versus anything to do with the query itself. It could be something on our network, the amount of hops the data has to flow through between the SQL Server and the destination, connection speed of the end user, and/or any number of other factors outside my control or ability to do anything about.

Thank you to all who have responded and provided suggestions. Many of which I will use going forward, and keep in mind as I work with the database.

Comment: create a #temp or @temp table (splitvalue primary key clustered).. insert distinct splitvalue from dbo.Split() into the temp table and join Mytable. with temp.

Comment: The queries look fine and the optimizer should find the optimal plan for them. It seems, though, it doesn't. I suppose it always goes for the index, even when with more data to look up, a mere sequential full table scan would be better. I don't know enough about SQL Server to say whether it is possible to help the optimizer here. You may find something in the docs. (A general "advice" is of course: the newer your SQL Server version, the better its optimizer usually.)

Comment: I think your problem is not the table but the dbo.Split() function. Query planner, especially on older versions of SQL Server, has horrible estimates on user-defined functions and makes a lot of stupid decisions because of it. @lptr's advice of inserting the output of dbo.Split() into a temp table and then joining on that is probably the best advice you can get without showing the code behind dbo.Split().

Comment: As previously mentioned, the best solution for you is to use temp table. Also, you can create index on temp tables - this can also be useful. Read more about this here -  https://www.sqlshack.com/indexing-sql-server-temporary-tables/

Comment: substring is really slow on large strings. You should consider turning to use XML XPath query by replacing the delimiter to ‵</i><i>‵. Remember to escape all characters correctly.
Another possible solution is to bisect your string in your algorithm. In this way, the average string size you are doing substring can be minimized.

Comment: @COY I'm sorry but I do not understand/follow your comment. The first suggestion I am not sure how converting to XML to then somehow identify the records will work or be faster. Can you provide an example? And the second suggestion, I am not sure I even know what you're saying, let alone know how I would do it. Again, example please?

Comment: 57% of the time is devoted to a sort.  Are you using ORDER BY, and can you avoid it?  Also, with your temp table, try WHERE EXISTS instead of a join.  That will prevent duplicates being produced from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are not falling into the trap of using different datatype for index seek of your main table (i.e. your PackageID is varchar but not nvarchar or numeric), then your table join itself is very fast.

To confirm this, you can split the process into 2 steps, insert into temp table, then use temp table to join. If the first step is super slow and the second step is super fast, then that affirms my assumption above.

If step 1 is slow, it means the main cause of the slow performance is on the Split which uses a lot of substring calls.
Assume your list has 10000 items of 20 bytes for each ID. It means you have a variable of 200KB.
By your current SUBSTRING call, it will always copy the 200KB into a new string on each iteration. The string will gradually decrease from 200KB to 0KB but you already copy the 100+KB string for 5000 times. This is 1000MB of data flow in total.

Below are 3 functions.
[Split$60769735$0] is your original function
[Split$60769735$1] is using XML
[Split$60769735$2] is using binary split, but also make use of your original function

[Split$60769735$1] is fast because it utilizes the specialized parser for XML that already can handle split very well.
[Split$60769735$2] is fast because it changes your O(n^2) complexity to O(n log n)

Run time is:
[Split$60769735$0] = 3 to 4 min
[Split$60769735$1] = 2 seconds
[Split$60769735$2] = 7 seconds

NOTE: as this is for demo purpose, some edge cases are not yet handled.
 1. For [Split$60769735$1], if the values may contain < > &, some escape is required
 2. For [Split$60769735$2], if the delimiter can be not found in the second half of the string (i.e. one child item can be as long as 5000 char), you need to handle the case when the charindex function does not return a hit.

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA [TRY]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [TRY].[Split$60769735$0]
( 
        @String VARCHAR(max), 
        @Delimiter VARCHAR(5) 
) 
RETURNS @SplittedValues TABLE 
( 
  OccurenceId INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
  SplitValue VARCHAR(max) 
) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @SplitLength INT 

    WHILE LEN(@String) > 0 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @SplitLength = (CASE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String) 
                                    WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@String) 
                                    ELSE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String) -1 
                                END)

        INSERT INTO @SplittedValues 
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, 1, @SplitLength)

        SELECT @String = (CASE (LEN(@String) - @SplitLength) 
                                WHEN 0 THEN '' 
                                ELSE RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - @SplitLength - 1) 
                          END) 
    END 
    RETURN 
END
GO
```

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [TRY].[Split$60769735$1]
( 
        @String VARCHAR(max), 
        @Delimiter VARCHAR(5) 
) 
RETURNS @SplittedValues TABLE 
( 
  OccurenceId INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
  SplitValue VARCHAR(max) 
) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @x XML = cast('<i>'+replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</i><i>')+'</i>' AS XML)
    INSERT INTO @SplittedValues 
    SELECT v.value('.','varchar(100)') FROM @x.nodes('i') AS x(v)
    RETURN 
END
GO
```

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [TRY].[Split$60769735$2]
( 
        @String VARCHAR(max), 
        @Delimiter VARCHAR(5) 
) 
RETURNS @SplittedValues TABLE 
( 
  OccurenceId INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
  SplitValue VARCHAR(max) 
) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @len int = len(@String);
    IF @len > 10000 BEGIN
        DECLARE @mid int = charindex(@Delimiter,@String,@len/2);
        INSERT INTO @SplittedValues
        SELECT SplitValue FROM TRY.[Split$60769735$2](substring(@String, 1, @mid-1), @Delimiter);
        INSERT INTO @SplittedValues
        SELECT SplitValue FROM TRY.[Split$60769735$2](substring(@String, @mid+len(@Delimiter), @len-@mid-len(@Delimiter)+1), @Delimiter);
    END ELSE BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @SplittedValues
        SELECT SplitValue FROM TRY.[Split$60769735$0](@String, @Delimiter);
    END
    RETURN
END 
GO
```

NOTE:
- starting from SQL Server 2016, there will be a built-in split function. But unfortunately you are in 2012

If step 1 is fast but step 2 is slow, possible issues are datatype mismatch or missing index. For such case, posting what your execution plan looks like will help most.

Comment: I'm trying to understand, truly I am, but I do not follow how changing the manner in which the incoming delimited list of ID's is broken apart will in any way affect how the records are pulled from the main table. I am dumping the Split ID's into a TempTable and joining that list of ID's against the main table to retrieve the relevant records. What difference does it make if I use XML or other means to make my ID list, once the list is made it's made?

Comment: dump Split ID to temp table will not help you. let me update the answer to tell more clearly why your split is slow.

Comment: How long does it take to run the split functionality on its own, without joining into the main table?

Comment: Oops, your ID list is shorter than I expected. If a list of 500 will cost this long, please do check your data type first. Is your PackageID numeric?

Comment: @COY the PackageID on the main table is INT and the Split table ID value is defined as INT. So yes, I made sure to go apples-to-apples here. But honest question though.

Comment: @philip-kelley The Split() part of the query (using my original or COY's XML version) takes so little time it can be measured in milliseconds. I ran several tests and it fluctuates between 110-126 milliseconds (old way) and 33-40 milliseconds (XML way) to complete the Split().

Comment: @AndrewRaastad based on the plan, I think you can try to test the run time change by: (1) remove any ORDER BY as the end; (2) remove columns selected and only select the ID for the join.

Comment: @COY I can remove the Order By, yes... but just pulling back the ID's? Yeah not going to happen. And by your saying that, I think you are missing the entire point of my post. The ID's are coming in as an argument for the SProc the discussed query is located in, I already know what they are, I am trying to pull back all the data in the table where the list of ID's match the ID's in the table.

Comment: @AndrewRaastad I understand your hold a string which lists the IDs. But it has a meaning when you split the ID and join them again in the table. The optimizer has to execute a similar query as the full query to output the IDs because to optimizer there is no guarantee the ID is found from the table. What happens to the plan and run time after you remove ORDER BY and other columns? Please make the update for us to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not much of an answer, but rather a bucket list. I see no obvious reason why this query performs poorly. The following are some unlikely, really unlikely, and ridiculous possibilities.

+1 on “make sure datatypes on either side of the join are identical”

+1 on loading the “split” data into its own temporary table.

I recommend a #temp table built with a primary key (as opposed to @temp), for obscure reasons having to do with statistics that I believe stopped being relevant in later versions of SQL Server (I started with 7.0, and easily lose track of when the myriad newfangleds got added).

What does the query plan show?

Try running it with “set statistics io on”, to see how many page reads are actually involved.

During your testing, are you certain this is the ONLY query running against that database?

“MyTable” is a table, right? Not a view, synonym, linked server monstrosity, or other bizarre construct?

Any third-party tools installed that might be logging your every action on the DB and/or server?

Give that PackageId is not unique in MyTable, how much data is actually being returned? It may well be that it just takes that long for the data to be read and passed back to the calling system—though this really seems unlikely, unless the server’s flooded with other work to do as well.

Comment: Curious--the posted query plan (added while I was writing the above) shows a SORT operation, taking 57% of the duration (probably). Do you have an ORDER BY clause? Do things go faster if you take it out?

Comment: @philip-kelly Yes we do, but after I saw that as well, I took it out and re-ran my tests.. unfortunately it only improved it on average by about 15 seconds on a near 7 minutes execution time.

Comment: @philip-kelly also, to answer your bucket list... the "MyTable" is a table, plain ol' boring ordinary table. No third party tools. This is a "private" SQL Server, meaning there are no outside parties, other teams, etc. hitting it without us knowing it, not hooked up to a public website, any of that. There is nothing else of any notable kind happening on it outside what I am doing currently.

Comment: I'd be tempted to fire up SQL Profiler, point it at the SQL instance, and see if it picked up something else going on while this query was running. Performance Manager too might be an option. Are database pulls on this box generally slow, or is it really just this one query? (This one table? This one database?)